# Repeat the Values in 'Null' places

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, self-join

We have multiple same id's and some of them have values and some of them are null, we wanted to copy the values where it is null.

Current scenario

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | null |

Expected

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | ABC |
| 1 | ABC |

Comment: What would be the result if another id = 1 row had DEF as value?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way will be to use aggregation function to get the value for the particular group:

```
SELECT id
      ,COALESCE(value, MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id)) As "value"
FROM table
```

Of course, you can use other aggregation function like MIN (to get the smallest of available values) or [STRING_AGG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.18.1.1.1) to get a list with the values.